# How can I make a ball move left and right continuously in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

Assuming that the below method is hooked up to a main method that creates a circle in a window and that I want this circle to move left about 100 pixels and then move right 100 pixels and so on.

I can't figure out the code to do it.

```
  private void moveBall() 
{
    boolean moveRight = true;

    if(moveRight == true)
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = x - 1;
    }

    if(x == 300)
    {
        moveRight = false;
    }




}
```

Comment: what are you having an issue with? What is it currently doing with that? P.S. You should have your `moveRight` variable outside of the method scope so that your `moveRight = false;` actually works. You will also need to set it back to true when x = left bounds

Comment: Currently, the ball moves right on initalisation, continues to move right, and moves right so much that it disappears off the screen never to return

Comment: In my head what I think should be happening is the value of x gets to 300 which then satisfies the else part of the if statement and should then start moving the ball left due to x = x -1, but that's not happening

Answer (score 1):

The reason the ball is continually moving right is because when it hits the if statement to set moveRight to false it resets it back to true at the start of the method. You need to pull `moveRight` to be a class variable if you want it to work like you think it should.

What about trying it like this?

```
//set the moveRight variable as a class variable
private boolean moveRight = true;

private void moveBall() {
    //move right or left accordingly
    x = moveRight ? x + 1 : x - 1;

    //if x == 300 we want to move left, else if x == 100 im assuming you want to move right again
    if (x == 300) {
        moveRight = false;
    } else if(x == 100){
        moveRight = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me what the ? and : do in the moveBall() method?

Comment: the ? : syntax is called a ternary operator http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: @J.Brown it's called a [ternary](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) is like an `if-else`

Comment: What it means is if the condition before the `?` is true set it to x + 1, if it is false, set it to 'x - 1'

Comment: That's fixed it perfectly. God damnit why couldn't I do that.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. So why wasn't that working with my code? Do you have any idea what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem was with variable scope. Read up on it :) It will help you out heh

Comment: Your variable as @austinwernli said was out of scope, it was a local variable which was reset each time you got into `moveBall()` method. Also I want to recommend you not to check boolean variables as `if (variable == true) { ` but `if (variable)` it does the same thing and prevents any typo like `if (variable = true) {` It would improve your code by a lot, and future headaches because of this :)

Comment: Thank you both, I appreciate your advice!

Comment: Of course! Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped :)